# R: How to shut down database in flexdashboard?

Tags: r, sqlite, duckdb

I have a flexdashboard which queries from a local DuckDB (similar to SQLite) but every so often it says:

```
Warning: Error in initialize: duckdb_startup_R: Failed to open database
```

There is no "onStop dbdisconnect" style command in my code (I'm not sure where to put it in flexdashboard) so it doesn't shut down correctly if my R instance crashes. My only solution is to restart the computer. How can I fix this?

Comment: I put ```onStop dbdisconnect``` right after ```dbConnect```.

Comment: Thanks José. Could you put the exact code you use please? flexdashboard doesn't seem to recognise onStop.

Comment: Funny, I read shinydashboard, by anyway gave it a try with flexdashboard and it worked: https://gist.github.com/jjesusfilho/d7ed3254d6ea5c6c5bdf1b798aebc020

Comment: Thank you, so far, flex hasn't complained about not being able to open the connection.